# How do I get just city-level data on data.gov?

Tags: data.gov, extracting

I want to get all the datasets with this icon next to them - how do I go about doing this ?
[image: I want to get all the datasets that have this icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the link to city level datasets in data.gov

http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?groups=local&organization_type=City+Government#topic=local_navigation

You will see there is only 2600 datasets, so there is still alot of city datasets not accessible from data.gov. In these cases, you will need to go to the city's own open data portal.

You can find a fairly extensive listing (links) to open data portals at the [US] city level the link below. This is a crowd sourced project for cataloging government data portals throughout the world.

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - OpenGeoCode - How does opengeocode compare to OKFN's open data census ? - http://us-city.census.okfn.org/ - Seems redundant.

Comment: You may also want to check out http://opendatanetwork.com/ where you can get a list of datasets by searching or filter by Socrata-powered open data site. (I work for Socrata and we built and maintain the Open Data Network)

Comment: @vr00n - our crowd source project was launched more than a year ago, at a time when there was no comprehensive catalog. I've seen OKFN's census a few times, and seems to be growing over time.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew-OpenGeoCode - yeah opengeocode looks pretty great. I especially like the fact that you can download a simple csv file of all catalog. 

Would you happen know of any existing efforts around cataloging unstructured local data i.e. datasets that are listed on some random HTML page rather that in a structured catalog.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `organization_type` filter on the [CKAN API](http://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/index.html), e.g.

```
http://catalog.data.gov/api/action/package_search?q=organization_type:%22City%20Government%22+AND+dataset_type:dataset
```

But as others have said, Data.gov is only including city datasets that have given Data.gov [permission to do so](https://www.data.gov/local/add) and who are providing their metadata using the [Project Open Data](https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema) (DCAT JSON) metadata standard. And even many of the cities that are providing metadata to data.gov this way are not currently able to include all of their metadata because of [a bug](https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/714) in the service they're using to publish their metadata. You can see stats on how many records are being left out because of this bug at http://dropbox.ashlock.us/temp/local/